# Android - Add volume control to system for my app

Tags: java, android

Good afternoon everyone, It's my first post here so please excuse me if I made some mistakes :)

Here is my problem :
I'm currently developing an app that control all most devices that are in a room. This work fine. I can control the Master Volume of my Amplifier, but now I want to be able to add a system volume seek bar, just like YouTube does for YouTube TV :[Screenshot of Android Volume Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOCVk.jpg) (4th seekbar).
I made a lot of research but was not able to find what I wanted. Maybe I don't have the good key word.

Thank for reading me

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-audio-manager-and-volume-control-adjustment/

it does exactly what you want

Comment: It is always better to briefly explain your proposed answer and then add a link to back it up and provide further details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I just look at your link, and it explain what I already saw in my research, it control system sounds, and I'm looking for a way to add a sound stream tout control my amplifier and not controling system sounds. YouTube app does this when your remote controling a YouTube TV device, it add a volume seekbar to volumes, and control YouTube TV, not à real sound stream playing on the Android device. Hope my reply is clear, thanks.